# Resource qualifier for landscape orientation only in phones

Tags: android

Is there a way to create a resource qualifier for landscape mode, but only for sphones? For large screens I'm using Fragments, so the layout in portrait mode really looks better for them. Currently my resources look like this:

```
resources/layout
resources/layout-w600dp
resources/layout-w1200dp
```

In `layout`, I have the layouts for the activities on phones and for the fragments in default (portrait) mode. The other two folders are for the activities in "medium" and "big" tablet screens. If I create a

```
resources/layout-land
```

To better support landscape on phones, It will be used for tablets on landscape. Duplicating the file from `layout` in `layout-w600dp-land` makes me itch... is there a way to do what I want without duplicating files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure you're trying to accomplish but I would read through this article to see if it helps answer your question:  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: Thanks! I "solved" it by creating different files for the layouts, like `main_port.xml` and `main_land.xml` and then creating a `layout.xml` file in different values folders (such as `values-sw600dp-land` and `values-land`) with a `main` item pointing to either `main_port` or `main_land`. Not sure if this doesn't make me itch even more, though... I wish there was a biggest width qualifier :(

Comment: Just what i needed. Good article